# What happens to an object between to massive objects?

Tags: forces

I want to understand how forces act on an object. I don't know anything beyond the high school physics so let me ask about gravity.

Suppose an object $A$ is placed at the middle of two objects $B$ and $C$ of the same mass. Assume that $B$ and $C$ are massive and close enough so that the magnitude of the gravity acting on $A$ by each object is extremely large. If $A$ were a point then two forces are cancelled and nothing will happen. But there is no point in the real world and any object should have some size. What will happen in this case? Would an object be torn apart as we can cut a string by pulling them from two sides?

Comment: _But there is no point in the real world and any object should have some size_  I am sorry, I don't understand what you are saying here as regards  no point, and an electron, for example,  is often treated as a dimensionless point.

Comment: I didn't know that we could treat an electron as a point. Since it has mass I thought it has some size, otherwise the density would be infinite. I don't know anything about physics, so could you recommend where I can learn about those point-like object?

Comment: Search amazon for popular quantum physics science books by, imo,  decent writers such as Sean Carroll, Jim Al-Khalili...then look at the table of contents and sample pages to see if you are interested in their subjects and can follow them.  We don't understand electrons fully, but these books should describe our theories at your level, no offence meant, nobody in the world fully understands all of physics. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Also, plenty on the Web for free if you look around, but some stuff is much better than others. Takes a while to see what's ok and what's  just hype and drama to sell their book.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that we treat an object as a point just for simplicity. It's quite surprising that physics people really think there is a point or infinity.

Answer (score 1):

We often treat small objects as dimensionless points but that in that case we take the assumption that the object's mass and size does not have a meaningful impact on the behaviour of the system we're measuring.

The force between a planet and the object is $F = G\frac{m_1 m_2 }{r^2}$

It's true that the object can be "torn apart", however in a real-world situation the chemical force that is keeping an object together is far more powerful.

Comment: Good summation, imo regards

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what the chemical force is? According to articles in the web, there are four known forces: gravity, electromagnetic, strong and weak. I thought that by letting the mass of $B$ and $C$ large, we could make the gravity dominating, while other forces remain insignificant. Then may I think it would be possible to decompose elementary particles further unless they are points?